# Authentication with MSAL.NET fails for some users

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm using MSAL.NET in a Windows Forms application to authenticate with our B2C tenant. It works most of the time, but for some users the following error occurs:

*The browser based authentication dialog failed to complete. Reason: The protocol is not known and no pluggable protocols have been entered that match.*

I think the problem has to do with the length of the code in the redirect url, exceeding the maximum length of the system browser url. But that's only a guess. What I do know is: if I remove a scope for the failing user, or remove something else from the token, authentication succeeds. And I noticed the length of the authorization code, depends on the size of the token.

Does someone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, due to the limitation of URL length, this error occurs in some browsers. This seems to be a common problem. If the return URL from the authorized endpoint is too long, the web dialog that MSAL uses to render the web page will block. This will happen as long as the authorization code returned by B2C is large enough.

In B2C, the size of the authorization code is proportional to the customization of the policy. Therefore, to work around this issue, developers can try to remove the claim from their strategy. This usually reduces the size of the authorization code.

please see: https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-NativeClient-DotNet/issues/1

Comment: Yes, it is probably the same issue as the github issue you mention. It is quite old, so I was hoping there was a solution by now, but unfortunately not.

Comment: The authorization code is not only proportional to the claims in the policy, but also to the content of the claims. Because if I request less scopes, the scp claim is smaller and login succeeds.